# iPhoneとiPadの挙動の違いについて

Tags: objective-c, xcode

いつもお世話になっております。

現在作成中のアプリはユニバーサルアプリなのですが、1つのStoryboardをAutoLayoutでiPhoneとiPadで共有しており、当然ソースも同じものを使っています。

iPhoneでは全く問題無く動くのですが、iPadでは

```
2015-05-03 17:58:43.703 AppName[6129:3070159] Received memory warning.
2015-05-03 17:58:48.103 AppName[6129:3070188] Communications error:     <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x38a1a614> { count = 1, contents =
"XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x38a1a86c> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }}>
2015-05-03 17:58:48.238 AppName[6129:3070159] Received memory warning.
```

と言うエラーが発生してクラッシュしてしまいます。

因みにiPhone 4sで試験もしてみましたが、xCodeからは何もエラーは出力されていませんでした。

もう一つ気になるのは、segueで画面遷移しているのですが、iPhoneの場合はNavigationBarのLeftButtonが「戻る」になっているのですが、iPadでは戻る画面のタイトルになっている事です。

理由や対処がお判りになる方がいらっしゃいましたら、御教授ください。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 微妙なところですから、それぞれのハードウェア・モデル名とiOS verくらいは、記したほうがいいでしょう。iPadとだけいうなら、厳密なかいしゃくでは、iOS5.1.1までしかあげれない初代iPadのことですし。あと、UISplitViewControllerを使っているのか、否かと、deployment targetは、何にしているのかも。